# ASP.NET Platform shows only AnyCPU in the dropdown

Tags: asp.net, .net

I need to change asp.net project Platform to x64, but unlike other projects in the solution, this project shows only AnyCPU in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Changed AnyCPU to X64 in the .cproj file.